# Competition research legality

Tags: intellectual-property, legal-terms, is-x-legal

Is it illegal to do competition research for somebody and thus **be paid** to do that? What if the competition has in its Terms of Use agreement a directive like: *User may not use any information on the website for commercial purposes.* Can this kind of analysis of a competitor be considered as commercial use? Note that the analysis (and all information contained) will be used for making some business decisions.

Comment: I'm not sure how the "for somebody" and the "be paid" is relevant. Additionally, a vague term like "commercial purposes" would not appear in good T&C of any business. The purposes of a company *are* commercial purposes. When Acme, Inc sells Widgets on their website, that is a commercial purpose.

Comment: So, basically, you are saying that I am not in violation of such Terms of Use if I do such analysis of a competitor? Even if I am using the results of the analysis for making some business decisions?

Comment: In most cases, if it is legal to do something it is legal to be paid to do it (having sex is an exception in many places). I am not clear what kind of "competition research" you think might be illegal if paid. Please be more specific on what sort of acts your are asking about